# Invoking .Net COM assembly from Powerbuilder application (without registration)

Tags: com, interop, manifest, registration, powerbuilder

We have a Powerbuilder 10 application that is using .Net COM assemblies. We are trying to embed the manifest in the PB application (to invoke COM assemblies without registration). The merged manifest file has added sections for dependecies on the .Net COM assemblies. We have tries various tools to inject the new manifest with different results
- using GenMan32 to inject truncates the application from 6MB to 45KB.
- using ResourceTuner, the file size looks okay, but trying to launch application gives "Fatal Disk Error".

Any suggestions on invoked .Net ComEnabled assembly from PB without registration?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it with an external manifest and ensured that works?  If an external manifest doesn't work, then the manifest information isn't correct.

Once you have a valid external manifest, you might try the Manifest Tool (MT.EXE) from the .Net SDK.  It works well with true EXE files.  As Terry noted though, the PB generated executable contains additional information that tools that manipulate the EXE need to respect or they will break it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/patricka/archive/2009/12/09/answers-to-several-application-manifest-mysteries-and-questions.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is more a redirection than an answer. One thing you need to be aware of is that PowerBuilder produces executables that do not follow standards for Windows executable files. Essentially they are a bootstrap routine to load the PowerBuilder virtual machine, plus a collection of class definitions (objects). The cases you've brought up are not the first I've heard of where utilities meant to modify executables don't work on PowerBuilder executables.

As for a positive contribution on what other directions to follow, I don't really know enough to give qualified advice. If it were me, I'd try to register the COM object if ConnectToNewObject() fails, but I've got no idea if that possible or if that route is a dead end.

Good luck,

Terry.